# behavior of call in Red language

Tags: red

On Red console, I tried the following commands:

```
>> (print 0 call/shell/wait "sleep 5" print 5)
```

I think `0` would be printed first. After 5 seconds delay, `5` would then be printed.
In fact, both 0 and 5 were printed after delay of 5s. Why?

Note: `sleep.exe` is an external command.

Answer (score 1):

The Red GUI console is buffering output too aggressively in order to provide fast output. A [fix](https://github.com/red/red/commit/a15845a9c621c17b3168c1af4ebd42769c6ec893) was just pushed, so it should now behave as you expect.

BTW, you don't need to enclose the whole line in `(..)`, it does not change anything in the way that code line will be processed.

Comment: How to use the `fix` you mentioned in my case?

Comment: Just download the latest binary version under section "Automated builds" from the official [download page](https://www.red-lang.org/p/download.html), or pull the changes from [Red repo](https://github.com/red/red) on Github, then manually rebuild a console.